# Using request with a post treatment

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I'd like to perform a request multiple times and handle a treatment on it.
As I have a result array in my class, i'd like to store the result of the request each time i'm calling it. Indeed, the request may have multiple results (ie result.links.next)

However, the request is only performed 1 time and didn't go to the next function of the async series

What am I doing wrong ?

```
APIManager.prototype.postTreatment = function (error, response, body) {

 if(error) return console.log("error :: ",error)

 if(response.statusCode !== 200) return console.log("Invalid statusCode returned :: ",response.statusCode);
 var result = JSON.parse(body);

 _.each(result.list,function(elem){
   this.results.push(elem);
 }.bind(this));

 //next result links
 this.nextUrl = result.links.next;
};

APIManager.prototype.request = function() {

  var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(this.config.login + ":" + this.config.password).toString("base64");

 url = this.config.host + this.config.api_people;

 var self = this;
 async.series([
    function(callback){
    request({
    url : url,
    headers : {
      "Authorization" : authenticationHeader,
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
  },self.postTreatment.bind(self));
},
function(){
  console.log("request :: nextUrl",this.nextUrl);
  console.log("request :: results",this.results);
  while(this.nextUrl !== false){
    console.log("there");
    request({
      url : this.nextUrl,
      headers : {
        "Authorization" : authenticationHeader,
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      }
    },self.postTreatment).bind(self);
  }
 }
 ],function(err, results) {
   console.log(err,results);
 });

};
```